# tcl split string with variables

Tags: string, variables, tcl, realpath

how can split the name in tcl?

```
NEW in ARCHIVE XVID/J/JURASSIC.WORLD
```

path is not always the same, it may also be so

```
/XVID-BOXSET/007.A.VIEW.TO.A.KILL
```

and set this as variable, one variable set the name and one the path.

I need the following variables:

Name example : `JURASSIC.WORLD bzw 007.A.VIEW.TO.A.KILL`

Path example : `XVID/J/ bzw /XVID-BOXSET/`

Answer (score 3):

```
set pn [lindex {NEW in ARCHIVE XVID/J/JURASSIC.WORLD} 3]
# -> XVID/J/JURASSIC.WORLD
set path [file dirname $pn]
# -> XVID/J
set name [file tail $pn]
# -> JURASSIC.WORLD
```

Comment: @now, the thing to do now is accept this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Well strictly speaking, `lindex` should not be used. The path in the first case is `NEW in ARCHIVE XVID/J` (it's just a directory name with spaces in it).

Comment: @Jerry: not according to the path examples in the question.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Ah! I agree then. Maybe OP forgot to add it in the desired path. Sadly, he doesn't appear to be coming back soon.